# Python Mysql issue with %s for the table

Tags: python, mysql

**Question**

Why does `%s` escape sequence not work in my Python script with MySQL package?

**Background and Code**

I have an issue with the following line:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO `%s` (Date, Counter_in, Counter_out, Interface_name) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, %s, %s, %s)""", (Equipment, In_Octets, Out_Octets, interface))
```

I get the following error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SNMP_Query.py", line 41, in <module>
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO `%s` (Date, Counter_in, Counter_out, Interface_name) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, %s, %s, %s)""", (Equipment, In_Octets, Out_Octets, interface))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 166, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 35, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'Sipartech.'itx6-f10-1'' doesn't exist")
```

I have double checked and the table `itx6-f10-1` and indeed it does exist.

Answer (score 1):

One mistake I can notice in your insert query is that you are write `Date` a column name  without (**`**) symbol, where date is [MySQL date type:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) keyword. So, in your query :-

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO `%s` (Date, Counter_in, 
                                    ^
```

should be

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO `%s` (`Date`, `Counter_in`,                    
                                     ^ added (`)
```

Second, I couldn't understand why MySQL:1146  Error? It happen when database files are missing.
As I can notice `%s` is working that is  how you could find database name from `Equipment` a Python variable in your code.

But why you are getting:

```
  'Sipartech.'itx6-f10-1''
             ^          ^  extra '
```

of-course this can't be a data base name and may be the reason for mysql error:1146 , you should get:

```
 'Sipartech.itx6-f10-1'
```

Check the code and query.

Also if you have doubt with `%s`, then you can use `string.formate()` function instead of `%s`. like:

```
      """  
      INSERT INTO {0} ( `Date`, 
                        `Counter_in`, 
                        `Counter_out`, 
                        `Interface_name`) 
       VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, {1}, {2}, {3})
       """.formate(Equipment, In_Octets, Out_Octets, interface))
```

Also, Remember if `In_Octets, Out_Octets, interface` are **not** integers then put `'` around each braces `{}` in query string.